# Lost bootstrap styling after switching from razor html.textboxfor to html.editorfor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, editorfor

Why did I loose my bootstrap styling after I switched from html.textboxfor to html.editorfor?

I switched because I wasn't getting email validation on the textboxfor, I get it now when I use editorfor, but I've lost my styling.

Here are some pics and my code

```
    [Required]
    //[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

here is my html

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @placeholder = "e.g. example@url.com" })
```

[image]

then I switched to editorfor

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @placeholder = "e.g. example@url.com" })
```

[image]

Comment: Unless your using MVC5.1 or higher, then the `EditorFor()` method does not support adding html attributes (and if your are using it, your syntax is wrong)

Comment: Note you can just use `new { @type="email" }` assuming you were using the `[DataType(DateType.EmailAddress)]` attribute

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what I need to do here. I'm using MVC 5.2.2. and I'll post a code snippet of my email proeprty with the attribues I'm using. I tried with and without attribues but nothing changed the styling

Comment: If you have MVC-5.2, then you just need to use the correct syntax - see the dupe (`new { htmlAttributes = new { .... }}`

Comment: No its not - try it! (and [here is the documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Bootstrap))